# Save CSV WITH BOM

Tags: excel, csv, asp-classic, character-encoding

I have asp page which creates csv file. The problem is that this csv file is created as UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM and when I open it, some signs are not visible correctly. What should I change to save it as UTF-8 WITH BOM?  If I convert it to UTF-8 WITh BOM manially in notepad++, it works.

Thanks.

```
    Response.Clear
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8;"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=goodsTransfer.csv"
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Response.Write "all my data"
    Response.end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Response.Write(ChrW(65279) & "all my data")
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. But what does it means. As i understand, it is BOM that indicates that this is UTF-16 file: (FEFF is in decimal 65279)

From wikipedia:
"UTF-16, a BOM (U+FEFF) may be placed as the first character of a file or character stream to indicate the endianness (byte order) of all the 16-bit code units of the file or stream."

But i can open it with notepad++, which supports only UTF-8.
Can you explain me a bit? Thanks.

Comment: As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17879474/416542: The character \ufeff is used for all UTF encodings. In fact this character actually is encoded as 0xEFBBBF in UTF-8 as stated in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The correct BOM for UTF-8 is:

```
Response.Write(ChrW(&HeF) & ChrW(&Hbb) & ChrW(&HbF) & "all my data")
```