# How to export a table to Excel with UTF-8 format in order to include accent marks in the words?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

This scripts helps to export SQL tables to Excel, however it doesn't export words with accent marks properly.

What I want is to fix this code in order to be able to export words with accent marks, for example México.

I'm don't know how to fix this code to export the text of the tables in UTF-8 format.

```js
/*      =================================
**      ====  Export to Excel - Js   ====
**      ================================= 
*/

var xport = {
  _fallbacktoCSV: true,  
  toXLS: function(tableId, filename) {   
this._filename = (typeof filename == 'undefined') ? tableId : filename;

//var ieVersion = this._getMsieVersion();
//Fallback to CSV for IE & Edge
if ((this._getMsieVersion() || this._isFirefox()) && this._fallbacktoCSV) {
  return this.toCSV(tableId);
} else if (this._getMsieVersion() || this._isFirefox()) {
  alert("Not supported browser");
}

//Other Browser can download xls
var htmltable = document.getElementById(tableId);
var html = htmltable.outerHTML;

this._downloadAnchor("data:application/vnd.ms-excel" + encodeURIComponent(html), 'xls'); 
  },
  toCSV: function(tableId, filename) {
this._filename = (typeof filename === 'undefined') ? tableId : filename;
// Generate our CSV string from out HTML Table
var csv = this._tableToCSV(document.getElementById(tableId));

// Create a CSV Blob
var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" });


// Determine which approach to take for the download
if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  // Works for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge
  navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, this._filename + ".csv");
} else {      
  this._downloadAnchor(URL.createObjectURL(blob), 'csv');      
}
  },
  _getMsieVersion: function() {
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
if (msie > 0) {
  // IE 10 or older => return version number
  return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)), 10);
}

var trident = ua.indexOf("Trident/");
if (trident > 0) {
  // IE 11 => return version number
  var rv = ua.indexOf("rv:");
  return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf(".", rv)), 10);
}

var edge = ua.indexOf("Edge/");
if (edge > 0) {
  // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
  return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf(".", edge)), 10);
}

// other browser
return false;
  },
  _isFirefox: function(){
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
  return 1;
}

return 0;
  },
  _downloadAnchor: function(content, ext) {
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.style = "display:none !important";
  anchor.id = "downloadanchor";
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);

  // If the [download] attribute is supported, try to use it

  if ("download" in anchor) {
    anchor.download = this._filename + "." + ext;
  }
  anchor.href = content;
  anchor.click();
  anchor.remove();
  },
  _tableToCSV: function(table) {
// We'll be co-opting `slice` to create arrays
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

return slice
  .call(table.rows)
  .map(function(row) {
    return slice
      .call(row.cells)
      .map(function(cell) {
        return '"t"'.replace("t", cell.textContent);
      })
      .join(",");
  })
  .join("\r\n");
  }
};
```

Comment: It is Javascript. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes. This question lists most of them:
[Encoding issues for UTF8 CSV file when opening Excel and TextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342492/encoding-issues-for-utf8-csv-file-when-opening-excel-and-textedit/22107376#22107376)

Are you on a Mac?

You may explicitly set the charset, in case text/csv defaults to a different charset, similar to this:

```
"type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8"
```

There is also a simple way of converting an html table to Excel. Excel can read HTML files, so viewing an HTML snippet with a mime type of ms-excel causes Excel to open the HTML as if it were a spreadsheet. In jQuery:

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#tableid').html()));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the CSV part I solved unicode issue with changing following code part

```
// Create a CSV Blob
var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" });
```

to this, to include UTF-8 BOM (with help from stackoverflow answers):

```
var blob = new Blob([
                new Uint8Array([0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]), // UTF-8 BOM
                csv
                ],
                { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
```