# Javascript: create UTF-16 text file?

Tags: javascript, utf-16

I have some string need to be a UTF-16 text file. For example:

```
var s = "aosjdfkzlzkdoaslckjznx";
var file = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(s);
```

This will result a UTF-8 encoding text file. How can I get a UTF-16 text file with string `s`?

Comment: Does your file need to be in a `data:` URL? 'cause you can easily do what you want with a Blob.

Comment: Yes, I need base64. But I don't like fileReaderAPI because it's asynchronous. It will make my app too complex. Do you have better suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you reevaluate your criteria. Web apps use async stuff, it's inevitable. But as it happens, using TextEncoder and creating a Blob URI won't be async. You don't need the File API because you're not reading a file, you're creating one.

Comment: I use the arrayBuffer directly convert to base64 with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a legacy polyfill of the native [TextEncoder](http://www.w3.org/TR/encoding/#interface-textencoder) API to transform a JavaScript string into an ArrayBuffer. As you'll see in that documentation, UTF16 with either endianness <del>is</del> was supported. Libraries that provide UTF-16 support in a Text-Encoder-compatible way will probably appear soon, if they haven't already. Let's assume that one such library exposes a constructor called `ExtendedTextEncoder`.

Then you can easily create a Blob URL to allow users to download the file, without the inefficient base-64 conversion.

Something like this:

```
s = "aosjdfkzlzkdoaslckjznx"
var encoder = new ExtendedTextEncoder("utf-16be")
var blob = new Blob(encoder.encode(s), "text/plain")
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Now you can use `url` instead of your `data:` URL.

Comment: Just note, UTF-16LE text file has a magic header(FF,FE or 255,254). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

Comment: I'm sorry but I found this doesn't works in Safari. Safari just doesn't support TextEncoder() . Is there any other solution for Safari?

Comment: You can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) for TextEncoder. I can recommend the one I linked, I've used it myself. It will create a TextEncoder object that behaves just like the native one (only if it's not avaialble natvely).

Comment: Oh this is my first time heard about polyfill. Thanks and it works!

Comment: TextEncoder does not accept an encoding string as a parameter any more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/TextEncoder

Comment: @skibulk thanks for the notification. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Related: [Javascript to csv export encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19492846/1017480)

This should do it:

```js
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function(){

 downloadUtf16('Hello, World', 'myFile.csv')
});

function downloadUtf16(str, filename) {

 // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6226189
 var charCode, byteArray = [];

 // BE BOM
  byteArray.push(254, 255);

 // LE BOM
  // byteArray.push(255, 254);

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  
    charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
    
    // BE Bytes
    byteArray.push((charCode & 0xFF00) >>> 8);
    byteArray.push(charCode & 0xFF);
    
    // LE Bytes
    // byteArray.push(charCode & 0xff);
    // byteArray.push(charCode / 256 >>> 0);
  }
  
  var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArray)], {type:'text/plain;charset=UTF-16BE;'});
  var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
 // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197511
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = blobUrl;
  link.download = filename;

  if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    link.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    link.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="download">Download</button>
```

Comment: Does the trick for me! but, in your example you are working with BE BOM, but encode your blob with charset UTF-16LE. Shouldn't that be UTF-16BE then?

Comment: You save my life.

Comment: Does this also work for Unicode surrogate pairs (see the [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and [codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) documentation), i.e. characters/emojis with a unicode value greater than 0xFFFF?