# HTML DOM Equivalent of Buffer.toString("utf16le")

Tags: html, buffer

I was playing around with the Nodejs `Buffer.from(<string>).toString("utf16le")` but I can't find an HTML/DOM equivalent without browserify and whatnot. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: This used to be possible with `TextEncoder`, but `utf-16` and `utf-16le` has been removed it seems. Maybe try a polyfill, like some mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937088/javascript-create-utf-16-text-file).

Answer (score 0):

```
function debuffer(array){
    let td=new TextDecoder
    let raw=new Uint8Array(array)
    return td.decode(ua)
}
```

should do the job