# A special character is appended before § in csv export in jquery

Tags: jquery, excel, csv

I am doing a CSV export using jquery.

My values have special characters in them. Also I need to use the separator as semi-colon.

My code is:

```
var array= [];
array.push("Item;Name;Value");
array.push("1;Test,1;Test § 17");
array.push("2;Test2;Test § 18");

var csvAudit = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    csvAudit.push(array[i]);
}
var csvExport = csvAudit.join('\n');

var csvFileName = "test.csv";
var contentType = 'text/csv;charset=utf-16';
csvExport = "\ufeff" + 'sep=;\r\n' + csvExport;
var csvFile = new Blob([csvExport], {
       type: contentType
});
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = csvFileName;
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
a.textContent = 'Download CSV';
a.dataset.downloadurl = [contentType, a.download, a.href].join(':');
a.click();
```

When I download the CSV using **Chrome browser** then, in my excel file I see:
Test Â§ 17 instead of Test § 17

If I remove the **'sep=;\r\n'** then the special character **Â** is escaped but the separator is used as comma and it shows data in wrong way, i.e., **Test, 1** are displayed in separate cell instead of one.

Is there any possible solution to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492846/javascript-to-csv-export-encoding-issue

Comment: @Mazz I looked into it but none of the solutions work for me because I am using the separator as semi-colon. If I remove the separator then the special character is not appended but then comma is used as default separator and its shows my data incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue by quoting the values in array in **double quotes** and removed the semi-colon separator and used comma separator instead.

The correct code is:-

```
var array= [];
array.push(""Item","Name","Value"");
array.push(""1","Test,1","Test § 17"");
array.push(""2","Test2,"Test § 18"");

var csvAudit = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    csvAudit.push(array[i]);
}
var csvExport = csvAudit.join('\n');

var csvFileName = "test.csv";
var contentType = 'text/csv';
csvExport = "\ufeff" + csvExport;
var csvFile = new Blob([csvExport], {
       type: contentType
});
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = csvFileName;
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
a.textContent = 'Download CSV';
a.dataset.downloadurl = [contentType, a.download, a.href].join(':');
a.click();
```

**Special character Â** was removed by appending **"\ufeff"**