# how to download hebrew csv file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying hebrew csv file using javascript on Chrome extension.

But I got failed string.

[image]

Here is my code snippet.

```
var csv = "Phone\nאני אוהב אותך\n";
var file = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv;utf-8'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: url,
    filename: name
}, function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(msg.url);
});
```

Comment: Are you setting the charset to utf-8? cant' tell by this code.

Comment: where should I set?

Comment: "var file = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv;utf-8'});" so yes, to me it seems that it is set.

Comment: Just to test and not as a real solution, but if you use the following url: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1280 and use the codes in the first column of the table (like &#x05D0; for Aleph etc), is the output correct in that case or not?

Comment: Actually, @DanielvanDommele it's not the obvious. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492846/javascript-to-csv-export-encoding-issue it should be set as following: `"data:text/csv;charset=utf-8`

Comment: Are you opening it with microsoft excel?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var csv = String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF) + "Phone\nאני אוהב אותך\n";  // <--- here
var file = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv;utf-8'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: url,
    filename: name
}, function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(msg.url);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me (in a HTML test page at least) to use utf-16 charset instead. It worked both for the entity codes and the actual hebrew characters to be printed as hebrew characters.

So, change

**{type: 'text/csv;utf-8'});**

to

**{type: 'text/csv;utf-16'});**

Comment: Sorry, still the same.