# Saving CSV file with hebrew text

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, encoding

When I save the CSV file I get the hebrew in gibrish, this is the code' I trying to put UTF-8 but still get gibrish.

```
var data = [
       ['שם פרטי', 'programmer'],
       ['שם משפחה', 'bus driver'],
       ['כתובת', 'Reindeer Hunter']
    ];

    function download_csv() {
        var csv = 'Name, Title\n';
        data.forEach(function(row) {
                csv += row.join(',');
                csv += "\n";
        });

        console.log(csv);
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'people.csv';
        hiddenElement.click();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the UTF-8 BOM as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952812/98493

Comment: Yes! i tried this but still get gibrish