# Avoid additional symbols in postgresql Database

Tags: postgresql, csv

Logically copying a data from MS word and posted it in PostgreSQL database through some web user interface. After posting the value when I take a CSV export and fetching the value I posed earlier, Then I am experiencing some additional symbols in the CSV file. But those symbols are not available when I query from database or opened the CSV in notepad.

the data I copied - `Improve scalability performance while controlling costs​`

the data I received in CSV- `Improve scalabilityÂ performance whileÂ controlling costsâ€‹​`

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably due to a mix of Windows-1252 and UTF-8 coding. On UNIX there is a tool called `file` where you can see what encoding it is. And `iconv` that converts between various encodings. Text-editors like `sublime text` have similar functionality.

Comment: This might a problem with word, a problem with the web interface, a problem with the csv import process, a problem with the database configuration, a problem with the csv export process, or a problem with how you open the csv file. Without further details, we can't really help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492846/javascript-to-csv-export-encoding-issue
This link solved me this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with extra symbols in the CSV file is probably the result of special characters or encoding errors encountered during the copying process from MS Word. Making sure you're using UTF-8 encoding, cleaning the content by pasting it into a plain text editor first, and checking for encoding and delimiter settings throughout both the CSV export and import operations can all help you fix the problem.

Hope it works :)