# Download CSV file (UTF 8) encoding ServiceStack

Tags: csv, utf-8, servicestack

I am new to ServiceStack. It has feature to provide csv file for the data but I need to download it in UTF8 format because I am getting some special characters. I have tried this config setting.

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            AppendUtf8CharsetOnContentTypes = new HashSet<string> { MimeTypes.Csv } 
        });
```

but no luck.. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack Text serializers already serialize to UTF8 by default. The configuration below only appends the UTF8 suffix so the full Content-Type returned is `text/csv; charset=utf-8`:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AppendUtf8CharsetOnContentTypes = new HashSet<string> { MimeTypes.Csv } 
});
```

It doesn't change what it's serialized to which is already UTF-8.

I've made a change that let you modify the UTF8Encoding used for the different Text Serializers in ServiceStack.Text [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/700a42dcc7e7f7bb3c8316f6f904fb068f72fcc9).

This will let you specify to emit a UT8 BOM for the CSV Serializer with:

```
CsvSerializer.UTF8Encoding = UTF8Encoding(true);
```

This change is available from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks for your reply mythz. I checked the file downloaded in Notepad++ and when I checked the encoding, it showed UTF-8 without BOM. When I modified that to UTF-8 only then the special characters were gone. Please let me know which is the setting I can change so that I can get the file in UTF-8 encoding only.

Comment: Sounds like it is utf-8 without BOM/byte-order-mark. BOM is optional - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom . You probably would have to customize the serializer to send the BOM sequence in the stream.

Comment: @RaulNoheaGoodness yes you're right but we can add BOM char in client side as described in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879198/adding-utf-8-bom-to-string-blob

Answer (score 1):

For ServiceStack versions > 5.x.x you must change your code like this

```
CsvSerializer.UseEncoding = PclExport.Instance.GetUTF8Encoding(true);
```

By default it is using `CsvSerializer.UseEncoding = PclExport.Instance.GetUTF8Encoding(false); // without BOM`