# Javascript export CSV encoding utf-8 issue

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I need to export javascript array to CSV file and download it. I did it but **'ı,ü,ö,ğ,ş'** this characters looks like **'Ä± Ã¼ Ã¶  ÄŸ ÅŸ'** in the CSV file. I have tried many solutions recommended on this site but didn't work for me.

I added my code snippet, Can anyone solve this problem?

```js
var csvString = 'ı,ü,ö,ğ,ş';

var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv; charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvString));
a.setAttribute('download', 'example.csv');
a.click();
```

Comment: You probably know that this solution will not work in `Internet Explorer` since this browser does not support using `data`-URIs this way. But at least you should it make working using `Firefox`. `Firefox` will not accept `click` events for elements which are not appended to the DOM. So you need appending your `A` element to the DOM and not only creating it. See example in my answer. But also read my conclusion. Using `CSV` this way is not a solution but part of many problems.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This depends on what program is opening the `example.csv` file. Using a text editor, the encoding will be `UTF-8` and the characters will not be malformed. But using `Excel` the default encoding for `CSV` is `ANSI` and not `UTF-8`. So without forcing `Excel` using not `ANSI` but `UTF-8` as the encoding, the characters will be malformed.

`Excel` can be forced using `UTF-8`  for `CSV` with putting a `BOM` ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) as first characters in the file. The default `BOM` for `UTF-8` is the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. So one could think simply putting `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` as first bytes to the string will be the solution. But surely that would be too simple, wouldn't it? ;-) The problem with this is how to force JavaScript to not taking those bytes as characters. The "solution" is using a "universal BOM" `"\uFEFF"` as mentioned in [Special Characters (JavaScript)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/2yfce773(v=vs.118)).

Example:

```js
var csvString = 'ı,ü,ü,ğ,ş,#Hashtag,ä,ö';
var universalBOM = "\uFEFF";
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv; charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(universalBOM+csvString));
a.setAttribute('download', 'example.csv');
window.document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

See also [Adding UTF-8 BOM to string/Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879198/adding-utf-8-bom-to-string-blob).

Using this, the encoding will be correct. But nevertheless, this only works properly if comma is the default list separator in your `Windows` locale settings. If not, if for example semicolon is the default list separator in your `Windows` locale settings, then all content will be in first column without splitting it by comma. Then you have to use semicolon as delimiter in the `CSV` also. But this is another problem and leads to the conclusion **not** using `CSV` at all but using libraries which can directly creating `Excel` files (`*.xls` or `*.xlsx`).

Comment: I using **WPS Office Spreadsheet** to open CSV file and this program still don't showing characters properly. I tried to open CSV file with **Microsoft Office Excel** and worked properly. So i understood my problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: This works well for getting Excel to open the file with the UTF-8 encoding but when I hit save (Ctrl+S) it saves it as a TSV text file and not as a CSV utf-8 file. Have you encountered this issue at all?

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, but this is another question and it is a Microsoft fault within the Excel application that it is not able saving CSV UTF-8 encoded. See also the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: @AxelRichter - I've used your solution on my own project, but the data I'm exporting is of Instagram captions, which include hashtags (#) - the UTF-8 BOM solution you provided is now cutting off the strings once it hits the first # character - any suggestions for getting the BOM to ignore the #? Thanks!

Comment: @tristanojbacon: Sorry, cannot reproducing. Works for me even if `#` character is in data.

Comment: The best answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side#52414433