# Characters get converted into special characters

Tags: java, utf-8, apache-poi, locale

I am using [Apache POI](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.16) to read the `.docx` file and after some operations write in `.csv`.
The `.docx` file I am using is in french, but when I write the data in `.csv` it convert some of french characters in special characters.
example `Être un membre clé` converted to `ÃŠtre un membre clÃ©`

Below code is used to write the file

```
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(bw);
        writer.writeAll(data);
```

which use `UTF-8` as default.

While debugging I have checked before writing to `.csv` the data is as it is. but its get converted while writing? I have set default locale to `Locale.FRENCH`

Is I missed something?

Comment: I think we need to also see how you are reading the docx file.  I don't know much about that file format but it would be helpful to see that code also.

Comment: Using `FileInputStream`, but when I debug up to write code. the data looks as it it.

Comment: Data, say student info. its came from client say school.

Comment: Do you understand that when we say "where is `data` from?" that we need to *see the code* or we can't help you?  Please post *all the code* that develops `data`.

Comment: You are creating a writer without explicitly specifying the character set. It is possibly writing it as UTF-8, while you are reading it as WIN1252 (or possibly if you made this error early, you are reading UTF-8 as WIN1252).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is `Excel` which reads the `UTF-8` encoded `CSV` as `ANSI`. This happens when you simply open the `CSV` in `Excel` without using the text import wizard. Then `Excel` always expects `ANSI` if there is not a `BOM` at the beginning of the file. If you would open the `CSV` using a text editor which supports  `Unicode`, all will be correct.

Example:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

class DocxToCSV {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);

  List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  data.add(new String[]{"F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"});
  data.add(new String[]{"Être un membre clé", "Être clé", "membre clé"});
  data.add(new String[]{"Être", "un", "membre", "clé"});

  Path path = Paths.get("test.csv");
  BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);

  //bw.write(0xFEFF); bw.flush(); // write a BOM to the file

  CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(bw, ';', '"', '"', "\r\n");
  writer.writeAll(data);
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();

 }
}
```

Now if you open the `test.csv` using a text editor which supports  `Unicode`, all will be correct. But if you open the same file using `Excel` it looks like:

[image]

Now we do the same but having

```
bw.write(0xFEFF); bw.flush(); // write a BOM to the file
```

active.

This results in `Excel` like this when `test.csv` is simply opened by `Excel`:

[image]

Of course the better approach is always using `Excel`'s [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857).

See also [Javascript export CSV encoding utf-8 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462764/javascript-export-csv-encoding-utf-8-issue/42466254#42466254) for the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Richter, works like champ. And yes excel is my editor for csv. looking perfect in notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Être un membre clé "UTF8" = ÃŠtre un membre clÃ© "ANSI"

check the char code of how you are reading the final file.